# Export mysql database using OUTFILE command into .sql format

Tags: php, mysql

Here I want to export the database into .sql format.I tried SELECT * INTO OUTFILE --- FROM --- command but it returns only records not whole structure of table.
The code is

```js
<?php 
//include("db.php");

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('ganga_hms');
$table_name = "accountant";
$backup_file  = "C:/xampp/htdocs/FinalHMS/accountant.sql";
$sql = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backup_file' FROM $table_name";

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not take data backup: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Backedup  data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

However I want to export table with its structure.
And also suggest me that how to export the whole database using php.

Comment: You may need mysqldump.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To dump database you need "mysqldump" tool, but if do not have this tool on server and can not install it, you'll need a complex script that runs on all of your tables and gathers table structure and data like this: http://davidwalsh.name/backup-mysql-database-php

Answer (score 0):

A couple of problems.  The OUTFILE command is going to spit out the selected columns as delimited data with headers that can later be used with the INFILE command to import the data again.  *The file extension "*.sql" usually refers to a SQLDUMP which is not what you are doing.  Using OUTFILE/INFILE usually results in a text file (*.txt).*

If you are truly trying to do a table/database backup, you need to use the built-in tools to mySQL to dump the tables(s) and its data to a file that includes a drop command, the description of the table (to recreate it), and a series of insert command to restore the data.
REFER TO:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

If you are trying to do it programmically, it will be a lot of work to reinvent the wheel.  You can use one of the many shells to script a backup of the database and its tables.
REFER TO:  http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/

Hope this helps!